# i make right triangle by first creating required spaces and then print triangle with numbers but it says dead code and dont print right triangle

Tags: java

i created array and store values in array and then tried to print them in right aligned triangle

```
        System.out.println("Enter size ");
        int input=console.nextInt();
        int []array=new int[input];
        for(int c=0; c<6; c++) {
//store values in array
        array[c]=console.nextInt();
            }
            int a=1;
        int b=6;
// to print spaces
        for(int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=b; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("");
        b--;

           }
// to print values of array with shape of triangle
        for(int k=1;k<=6;k++ ) {
        for(int m=0;m<a;m++ ) {
        System.out.print(array[m]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        }
        break;
            a++;

        }

        }
```

Comment: Java, maybe? Please add your language as another tag.

Comment: Dead code means that the code can never be reached during execution. You will have to modify that piece of code.